# Javascript - Assign value of reference returned by function

Tags: javascript, reference

I have a function of the prototype of an object called `getComponent` which returns `this.components[name]`

```
function Foo()
{
    this.components = {"Scripts": [...], "Sprites": [...], "States": {...}, etc };
}

Foo.prototype.getComponent = function(name)
{
    return this.components[name];
}
```

Then I have some code that gets a component and sets it to something else...

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.getComponent("Sprites") = [];
```

This obviously raises the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Is there anyway to set the value of the returned value?

I don't want to access the objects variables directly: `foo.components.Sprites = []`.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: you could create a `setter` method just like the `getComponent` method to update the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can assign values to variables, constants and to the properties of objects.

A function returns a value. It never returns a variable, constant or property (not even if it reads one of those to get the value).

---

Either:

- create a `setComponent` method which takes two arguments and assigns the value of the second one to the property.
- rename your method to `component` and have it take an optional second argument and then act as either `setComponent` or `getComponent` depending on how many arguments were passed.